# Need to see latest incoming messages

Tags: wordpress, email, activities

we are a small charity who would like to see all the latest incoming enquiries from our website in one place when we log on to civicrm in wordpress.

We have created a general enquiry form (Caldera Forms) which does send an email direct to the specified charity email address, and does create an individual record at the backend of civicrm, but none of them show up in the activities screen when we log in.

It would be very useful to be able to see in one place the messages that we need to deal with as they come in.

Grateful in advance for any help on this please.

Answer (score 2):

As @petednz mentioned, it does sound like that your entries are being merged. You can check what dedupe rule Caldera form is using under the Contact 1 processor.  if you didn't create a dedupe rule that always create a new record, then it is likely that it will use an existing rule that merges the new entries.  To create a dedupe rule that doesn't merge, you need to get to CIVICRM and go to Contacts>Find and Merge Duplicate Contact and create a rule under the Individual Section.  Click Add Rules for the section and i suggest the following entries:

Rule Name = Always No Merge

Usage = General

Reserve = No tick

Field =    Address Name

Weight (same row as Address Name) = 10

Skip    the rest of    the rows

Weight Threshold to Consider Contacts    'Matching':100

the idea is to set a dedupe rule that will never be matched, more on how the dedupe rule works is here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/

then go back to Caldera Contact 1 Processor and refresh the browser.  You should see the new dedupe rule "Always No Merge" listed there for you to select.  Any new entries would be a new record now.  However, if the records do belong to the same individual, you would have the merge the records manually.

Answer (score 1):

Do you create Activity from Caldera form when user submits the Enquiry form? If not than you will need to add Processor to create an activity against the contact who submitted the form.

Comment: HI, I have added a civicrm activity processor

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that it does not make any difference. Nothing at all shows in the activities screen, so not sure what I'm doing wrong? I also have the contact processor attached, and as I said before, the emails come through to the domain email address no problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get a single view of the new messages.  if you are using activity processor, then setting it up to record as an associated activity with the contact record should work (https://github.com/mecachisenros/cf-civicrm/blob/master/docs/processors.md).  The other ways are to use the tag processor to add tags or use a group processor to add the contact to a designated group.  you can then use the CIVICRM dashboard to be updated on new entries.

However, Activity Processor should work, perhaps you want share how you setup the processor, it should be similar to the link i listed above.

Comment: I have the activities processor set up as follows: Contact Link
Link to
Contact 1
Select which contact you want to link this processor to.

Activity
Activity Type
Initial Enquiry
Activity Status
Completed
Campaign
Activity fields
Subject
Nature of enquiry [nature_of_enquiry]
Activity Date
date:Y/d/m
Duration
Location
Details
Comments / Questions [comments_questions]
Is Starred
Created Date
date:Y/m/d
Modified Date
Tags
Attached Files
No advanced_file or file or cf2_file in form
Cases
Is Activity Overdue
Target Contact ID
Source Contact ID
Assignee Contact ID

Comment: Nothing ever appears in the main activities screen when you log on, but if you click on the double headed arrow in the top right corner of the activities dashlet, it opens into a larger activity dashlet window and shows the latest form submitted. The problem there, is that it shows submissions over several months i.e.11th Feb, 11th April, 11th May by one applicant even though it has only just been submitted once just now, it the merges all of this under the current submission date. It also shows on the bottom, 1 of 6 records but the next etc keys do not work so you cannot flick between records

Comment: Have just worked out what it means by 1-6 of 6 entries. It is referring to the number of entries of the one single record as follows: Contact Merged 
Contact ID 203 has been merged and deleted.
Dog, Mad Dog, Mad n/a November 2nd, 2020 8:41 PM 
Completed
ViewEditDelete
Contact Deleted by Merge 
Contact ID 203 has been merged into Contact ID 202 and deleted.
Dog, Mad n/a n/a November 2nd, 2020 8:41 PM 
Completed
ViewEditDelete

Comment: Initial Enquiry 
Test
Dog, Mad n/a n/a May 11th, 2020 12:00 AM 
Completed
ViewEditDelete
Initial Enquiry 
Test
Dog, Mad n/a n/a April 11th, 2020 12:00 AM 
Initial Website Enquiry
ViewEditDelete
Initial Enquiry 
Test
Dog, Mad n/a n/a February 11th, 2020 12:00 AM 
Initial Website Enquiry
ViewEditDelete
Initial Enquiry 
Test
Dog, Mad n/a n/a February 11th, 2020 12:00 AM 
Initial Website Enquiry
ViewEditDelete

Comment: Firstly I don't understand why it's merging with other files when this enquiry has only just been created, and secondly, I don't understand why it does not register to day's date 05/11/20 anywhere when that is the date the enquiry was created?

Comment: I have just checked the contact records, and found that it seems that any new submission from the 'Initial Enquiry Form' overwrites any previous enquiry entry from another submission so that only the latest contact appears! Any idea why it would do that?

Comment: @BobWoolnough Your activity processor settings are helpful, but very hard to read in a comment.  Could you please edit your original question to include them, formatted for easy reading?

Comment: Contact Link
Link to - Contact 1
.

Activity
Activity Type - Initial Enquiry
Activity Status - Completed
Campaign
Activity fields
Subject - Nature of enquiry [nature_of_enquiry]
Activity Date - date:Y/d/m
Duration
Location
Details - Comments / Questions [comments_questions]
Is Starred
Created Date - date:Y/m/d
Modified Date
Tags
Attached Files - No advanced_file or file or cf2_file in form
Cases
Is Activity Overdue
Target Contact ID
Source Contact ID
Assignee Contact ID

Comment: Is this any better? Don't seem to be able to do much in the way of formatting in these comment boxes! Unless I'm missing something, which wouldn't be unusual LOL

Comment: maybe you need to check your dedupe/matching set up. sounds like the form is submitting and just overwriting the previously created contact